# Unable to convert between java.lang.Integer and BINARY.- Spring

Tags: java, sql, spring

I have the following DTO that I use to persist new records to my database

```
@Entity(name = "User")
public class User {

@Id
@Column(name = "User_Id")
private long userId;

@Column(name = "User_Name")
private String userNm;

@Column(name = "years_active")
private long years;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "Manager_Id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Manager manager;

@Column(name = "Projects",insertable = false, updatable = false)
private LinkedHashMap<Long, String> projects;

@Column(name = "Projects")
private long projectId;

@Column(name = "address")
private Address address;

//getters & setters

}
```

DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[User] (
[User_Id] int NOT NULL,
[User_Name] varchar(255) NOT NULL,
[years_active] int NOT NULL,
[Manager_id] int NOT NULL, //FK to Manager table
[Projects] int NOT NULL,   //FK to Project table
[Address] int NULL,        //FK to Address Table
[ModifiedBy] varchar(255) NOT NULL,
[ModifiedTS] datetime NULL)
```

I have no problem persisting data to this table via form submission, however when I try to retrieve an entity object using Spring Repository:

```
User user = userRepo.findOne(id); // id == Long, passed through @Controller method
```

I consistently get the following error : `Unable to convert between java.lang.Integer and BINARY.`

```
o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unable to convert between java.lang.Integer and BINARY.
o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command : 
org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Could not read entity state from ResultSet : EntityKey[com.myapp.entities.User#3]
```

I'm not sure where this conversion between integer and Binary is happening; any ideas?

Comment: Your table definition is relevant, please paste it in. My guess is one of the integral columns is declared as a string (e.g. `VARCHAR`, `CHAR`)

Comment: @Amadan Included DDL

Comment: I am not a Hibernate expert, but you have two `Projects` column mappings; one of them is a `LinkedHashMap`, which I am not sure works. I'd think you would want `@ManyToOne` and `@JoinColumn`, and not `@Column` for that.

Comment: What is com.bofa.curator.entities.LkpFeed? It seems the exception is relevant to this entity.